# The role of access specifiers on typedefs and forward declaration

Tags: c++, typedef, nested-class, forward-declaration, access-specifier

Consider the following sample code for a linked list type class. I wish to declare a method which returns an Iterator, which is a `typedef` for a `Node*`. However, `Node` is a private nested class so in order to make the `typdef`, i am required to let the compiler know about `Node` with a forward declaration.

Naively, I thought having both defaulted to private would work; something like this:

```
class List
{
    class Node;
    typedef Node* Iterator;
public:
   List() : head_(NULL), tail_(NULL) {} 
   Iterator begin() {return head_;}

private:
    class Node
    {
        private:
        int data_;
    };

    Node* head_;
    Node* tail_;
};

int main()
{
    List list;
    List::Iterator = list.begin();
    return 0;
}
```

which results in a compile time error at line 4:

> 'typedef class List::Node* List::Iterator' is private 
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

It isn't difficut to see why the forward declaration `class Node;` belongs in the private section, but what about `typedef Iterator Node*;`? This probably owes to my lack of understanding for the `typedef` keyword, but why does it matter which access specifier is applied? I thought `private` makes more sense because of the visibility of the `Node` class.

Does this have something to do with `typedef`s being part of the public interface? Do all typedefs have to be declared with `public` visibility?

---

*Edit:*
Allow me to clarify, I understand that I can stop my compiler from complaining by moving the typedef to public. What I don't understand is why this is necessary.

Comment: If I add a semi-colon at the end of the class definitions, I don't get any error. Is this your real code?

Comment: Ah, so it does.. It's just a simplified version. I'll see if i can recreate the error

Comment: @StickyCube - maybe you were trying to use `Iterator` type from a non-friend class/function?

Comment: Ok, i added a little implementation. I get the error again now

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make typedef name a public name. Try the following

```
class List
{
public:
    typedef class Node* Iterator;
```

Also take into account that for both classes you forgot to place semicolons after closing braces.:)

Answer (score 1):

`List::Iterator` is private, so the name cannot be used, but the type can be deduced

```
List l;
List::Iterator it = l.begin(); // Illegal
auto it = l.begin(); // legal
```

or

```
template <typename IT>
void foo(IT it);

foo(l.begin()); // legal
```

BTW, you may have `List::Iterator` public, and keep `List::Node` private.